# Как сделать триггер update, чтобы он прописывал в журнал "имя таблицы" и "поле"? - MySQL

Tags: mysql, триггер

Используется 
MySQL - 5.7 - х64

**Основная таблица 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `trg_02_1_test` (
    `id_tbl_02_1` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cur_datetime_tbl_02_1` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `pol_1_date_tbl_02_1` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pol_2_enum_tbl_02_1` ENUM('Y','N') NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pol_3_longtxt_tbl_02_1` LONGTEXT NULL,
    `pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1` TEXT NULL,
    `pol_5_int_tbl_02_1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id_tbl_02_1`)
)
LONGTEXT\r\n'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
AUTO_INCREMENT=7
;
```

**Таблица журнала**

```
CREATE TABLE `trg` (
    `datetime_log` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `tbl_02_name_log` TEXT NULL,
    `id_tbl_02_n_log` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `tbl_02_pol_name_log` TEXT NULL,
    `tbl_02_pol_content_log` TEXT NULL
)
LONGTEXT\r\n'
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
;
```

**Триггер для журналирования**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `trg_02_1_test_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `trg_02_1_test` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO trglog
     Set
     id_tbl_02_n_log = NEW.id_tbl_02_1,
     tbl_02_pol_content_log = NEW.pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1;

END
```

Предполагается в журнал помещать данные из нескольких таблиц.

**Вопрос.**
Как сделать, чтобы в журнал:

в поле **`tbl_02_name_log`** - подставлялось наименование **таблицы** в которой происходит обновление;
- в поле **`tbl_02_pol_name_log`** - подставлялось наименование **поля** в которой происходит обновление;

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как сделать, чтобы в журнал:
>
> в поле tbl_02_name_log - подставлялось наименование таблицы в которой происходит обновление;

Скопировать имя таблицы из заголовка триггера (первая строка твоего кода, между словами ON и FOR). Только как строковый литерал.

> - в поле tbl_02_pol_name_log - подставлялось наименование поля в которой происходит обновление;

Написать INSERT для каждого поля таблицы, подставляя имя обрабатываемого в данный момент поля как литерал. Соответственно запросов INSERT будет столько, сколько в таблице полей (или собирать динамический текст на добавление нескольких записей, а потом единым запросом выполнить).

А чтобы не писАть лишнего - сравнивай OLD.f и NEW.f, и выполняй INSERT только при неравенстве. Шаблонно:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggername
AFTER UPDATE ON tablename
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF OLD.fieldX <=> NEW.fieldX THEN
    INSERT INTO log
    SET fieldname = 'fieldX'
      , oldvalue  = OLD.fieldX
      , newvalue  = NEW.fieldX;
END IF;
/* one IF per each FIELD */
END;
```

Comment: @ Akina 
Выдаёт  ошибку синтаксиса - 1064
см. скрин http://prntscr.com/e9tg13  / Вопрос.
В чём может быть проблема?
[syntax=mysql]
delimiter//
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_02_1_test_before_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `trg_02_1_test` FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   /* поле pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1 */
  IF ( NOT OLD.pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1 <=> NEW.pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1) 
    THEN  
  INSERT INTO trglog
     Set     
  id_tbl_02_n_log = NEW.id_tbl_02_1,
    tbl_02_pol_content_log = NEW.pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1,
  tbl_02_pol_name_log = 'pol_4_txt_tbl_02_1';
 END IF; 
 tbl_02_name_log = 'trg_02_1_test';
END//
[/syntax]

Comment: А чё за хрень между `END IF;` и `END//`?

Comment: это я пока "въезжаю"... экспериментальное решение... подумал: для каждого поля будет IF, то зачем прописывать в каждом IF имя таблицы. Может просто вынести один раз.... Т.е. в зависимости от ситуации (от того какое поле обновляется) отработает тот или иной IF, а строка для, которая прописывает имя таблицы в которой происходит обновление, будет одна на весь триггер